# Measuring body temperature through touchscreen

Tags: android

I read somewhere that body temperature can be measured through touch screen since different body temperature induces different charge on the capacitive screen.Is it possible? If yes,how can the value be recorded and converted to corresponding temperature?

Comment: Where did you read that?

Comment: Listening for the first time where did you read it. any link for reference

Comment: Possibly related research: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1893687

Comment: From what I understand about this topic, yes different temps will produce different charges running through the screen but I believe the current hardware on treats it like a switch (I could be wrong). There is something called MotienEvent.getPressure() which returns a float between 0 and 1 but not exactly what it defines as "pressure". May be something to further look into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different charge for device means different coordinates. So you can't say exactly - is it temperature changed, or user just move his finger.

Actually, charge doesn't depends on temperature so much.